# Что представляет собой фреймворк telephony-common.jar?

Tags: android

Не знаю, разрешены ли здесь вопросы на тему прошивок, но все же я рискну. Есть официальная прошивка и залоченный модем (под оператора связи). Есть портированный `СyanogenMod` с аппарата-донора. Так вот, эта самая блокировка оператора где проявляется? Какие файлы за нее отвечают? Дело в том, что я заметил полностью разный код в `system/framework/telephony-common.jar`. Выходит, все системные приложения, отвечающие за телефонию зависят от этого фреймворка??

Мной проделан огромный путь (нужно всего-то вызвать один метод)

```
system/framework/telephony-common.jar/classes.dex >> dex2jar >> classes.dex.dex2jar.jar >> JdGui >> com/android/internal/telephony/IccCard/supplyNetworkDepersonalization(String nck, Message complete);
```

Comment: При замене Вы вряд ли получите кирпич, но 80%, что телефон и многое связанное работать не будет. Не скажу как у Вас, т.к нет подробностей, но на LG G2 разочка сводится к получить рут, заменить содержимое папки carrier уже правленным и удалить telephony.db, otacerts.zip. telephony-common.jar никак не нужно модифицировать.

Comment: я имел ввиду, что telephony-common.jar мне нужен исключительно для тестирования (как на официальной прошивке). Насчет вашего способа разлочки - да, на некоторых моделях это провернуть - раз, два и готово, но на некоторых особенных (Micromax Q415. Qualcomm) где такие детсткие лазейки скрыты и модифицированы фреймворки (+ сам модем) это выполнить нельзя. Разлочку я себе представляю обычным перебором от 00000001 до 99999999. Другого способа просто нет. Но меня смущает, что есть такая штука как попытки ввода верного nck  и возможно интервал между попытками (есть он или нет)

Comment: конкретнее - telephony-common был модифицирован производителем - в интерфейсе IccCard имеется метод GetPersoLockedRetries который возвращает оставшиеся попытки ввода. В микромаксе походу торопились и написали его с большой буквы, этот метод пояявился в оф, обновлении системы, вместе с ним и интерфейс для ввода NCK кода все это я декомпилировал и изучал

Comment: в циане же это метода нет и вообще никакого интерфейса для ввода кода нет, прошивка портирована и естественно связующие звенья между модемом и начинкой исчезли, получается чтобы протестировать приложение надо чтобы telephon-common был родной а прошивать родную прошивку не охота - хотелось бы на циане остаться и тестить, Ведь по сути блок на операторы на циане остается значит прошивка этот момент не трогает а значит и интерфейс к это штуке можно сделать но вот как быть если telephony-common не подружится с приложениями телефонии (особенно процесс com.android.phone я думаю он сразу упадет)

Comment: @Flippy вопрос еще актуален?

Comment: @Lex Hobbit, да, актуален

Comment: @Flippy а ссылочкой на конкретный интересующий вас telephony-common.jar не поделитесь? а то они достаточно сильно у разных производителей отличаются ...

Comment: @Lex Hobbit, да, вот вырвал из deodex прошивки стоковой https://yadi.sk/d/iRwopAIs3LYoZ3

Comment: @Lex Hobbit, самое интересное что не получается найти класс который интерфейс `IccCard` имплементирует, не могу найти как работает `getPersoLockedRetries`

Comment: @Flippy боюсь давать ответ, так немного не понимаю в чем конкретно проблема... давайте в чат, а там уже обговорим все детали

Comment: @Lex Hobbit, а где чат? :)

Comment: @Flippy что то у меня этот акк на se  не привязывается

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63097/discussion-between-lex-hobbit-and-flippy).